# Show on desktop, Then Hide Banner Advertisements on mobile

Tags: css, hide, show

Is there a bit of css @media coding i could use that would help me with showing and hiding some banner advertisements on a site?

Like, On desktop view,the leaderboard ads of 728x90 is showing, but on mobile, i would like to hide the leaderboard and go to 468x60 or 300x250??? I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: what have you done so far? provide us some code so we can try to help you about this matter

Comment: so I have a div with the id of largeAds and this is the css @media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   div#largeAds { display: none }
} It hides the leaderboard for me as it should, I just dont know how to SHOW the other size ads?

#largeAds { font-family:arial; width:728px; height:90px;  margin:0px auto 20px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try hide the small ads by default at first by using `display: none;`. Under the media query make it visible by applying `display: block;` and hide the large ads. You can see the example here http://jsfiddle.net/tkxCk/

Comment: Ok, great, I will try this. Thanks. I will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Worked Great! Hey thanks very much for your knowledge and time Qiqi